# SSH Remote Port Forwarding Empty Response

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I am trying to Remote port forward from Raspberry pi in my local network using ssh on my windows pc

```
ssh -R 5941:localhost:8000 pi@192.168.1.191
```

So from the above command, I am trying to forward connections from port 5941 on Raspberry pi server (192.168.1.191) to port 8000 on my pc (localhost) which hosts a web server on port 8000

The above ssh command executes with no errors but when i try to access http://localhost:5941/ on Raspberry Pi (192.168.1.191) i get

```
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I have tried

1. Turned off firewall on my Windows PC
2. netstat on raspberrypi gives me

```
$ sudo netstat -a | grep 5941
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5941        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5941               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

3. when i run the ssh command in verbose mode
   `ssh -R 5941:localhost:8000 pi@192.168.1.191 -v`
   I get this

```
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:5941 forwarded to local address localhost:8000
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: console supports the ansi parsing
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: Forwarding listen address "localhost" overridden by server GatewayPorts
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 5941, connect localhost:8000
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

and when i try to access http://localhost:5941/ on Raspberry Pi (192.168.1.191) i get this on ssh console

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 5941, originator ::1 port 58122
debug1: getsockopt TCP_NODELAY: Invalid argument
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([::1]:8000) in progress, fd=7
debug1: channel 1: new [::1]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 1: connected to localhost port 8000
debug1: channel 1: free: ::1, nchannels 2
```

How should I further diagnose my problem ?

Comment: What service is running on localhost:8000 on the local system? Is the process which provides this service logging any messages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution to this is to put `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

```
ssh -R 5941:127.0.0.1:8000 pi@192.168.1.191
```

This forces ipv4 instead of ipv6, for some reason ssh port forwarding in windows fails to work on ipv6, I was able to work the same command with `localhost` on linux just fine.

I found the solution from this post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1011000/open-source-remote-access-using-vnc-and-reverse-ssh)

Comment: For other's who may land here, I made the change above (i.e. 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost") into a "gcloud compute ssh .." port forwarding command into a GCP windows server VM and my ZMQ REQ/REP python connection suddenly came alive.

Comment: Don't forget to enable: ```AllowTcpForwarding yes``` and
```GatewayPorts yes``` in ```/etc/ssh/sshd_config``` and restart the SSH service after changes: ```sudo systemctl restart sshd```