# Nmap scan returns all ports open when ran with proxychains through a Linux <-> Windows SSH tunnel

Tags: sockets, ssh, ssh-tunnel, socks, nmap

I have been doing some experimenting with SSH dynamic port forwarding between Windows and Linux machines and have ran into a frustrating problem. The issue concerns the behavior of Nmap when running it via proxychains through a tunnel between the opposite OS's.

On the Linux side, I run a Debian distro and have tried with two versions of ssh/sshd, (OpenSSH_8.8p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.1.1o) and (OpenSSH_9.6p1 Debian-3, OpenSSL 3.1.4).

For Windows, I have tried using ssh from both a Windows 10 (OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2) and a Windows 11 (OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3) machine.

I have created dynamic port forwards in the following ways:

1. From Windows, run `ssh -vvv -R 9050 user@Linux` to connect to an ssh server on the Linux machine and open port 9050 on the Linux machine that dynamically forwards traffic through the Windows machine.
2. From Linux, run `ssh -vvv -D 9050 user@Windows` to connect to an ssh server on the Windows machine and open port 9050 on the Linux machine that dynamically forwards traffic through the Windows machine.

In both cases I run into the same problem, wherein **Nmap scans ran from the Linux machine through proxychains return all ports open on the scanned target.** The Nmap syntax I am using is: `nmap -Pn -n -sT -p445 --reason <ip>`, so no host discovery, no name resolution, full TCP connect scan for port 445, etc. For the purpose of this experiment, port 445 is **not** open on the target machine, and the target machine is a third machine that is reachable by both machines.

Running Nmap against the target without proxychains performs as expected, correctly returning that port 445 is not open on the target:

```
nmap -Pn -n -sT -p 445 --reason 192.168.1.160
Starting Nmap 7.94SVN ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-21 14:46 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.160
Host is up, received user-set (0.000078s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE      REASON
445/tcp closed microsoft-ds conn-refused

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

Running the same command through proxychains via the Windows <-> Linux tunnel however returns a false positive:

```
proxychains nmap -Pn -n -sT -p 445 --reason 192.168.1.160                                                                                          130 ⨯
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16
Starting Nmap 7.94SVN ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-21 14:46 EDT
[proxychains] Strict chain  ...  127.0.0.1:9050  ...  192.168.1.160:445  ...  OK
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.160
Host is up, received user-set (2.0s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE      REASON
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds syn-ack

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.05 seconds
```

I have also repeated this same experiment with Linux <-> Linux SSH dynamic port forwards and did not observe the same results/things worked properly. I have not fully explored the behavior between Windows <-> Windows tunnels, as I would really prefer to use Linux for one end of this.

The SSH output has some info that stands out. This is the output from the successful Linux <-> Linux tunnel Nmap scan, with the highlighted area showing the connection attempt and refusal due to the port being closed:
[image: Linux <-> Linux tunnel Nmap SSH debug output]

Compare this with the SSH output from the Windows -> Linux (ssh -R 9050...) tunnel when running the same Nmap command, where several errors occur:
[image: Windows -> Linux tunnel Nmap SSH debug output]

The first error is near the beginning of the highlighted sections:

```
debug3: socketio_getsockopt - ERROR:10022
debug1: getsockopt TCP_NODELAY: Invalid argument
```

The TCP_NODELAY flag is being identified as invalid, while the same flag appears to be used in the Linux <-> Linux tunnel without issue. From what I was able to find, error `10022` is a generic socket failure. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67199614/ssh-remote-port-forwarding-empty-response) as well as [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1011000/open-source-remote-access-using-vnc-and-reverse-ssh) by researching the invalid argument error, but they don't really seem to apply to this situation.

Other tools, like ssh and smbclient for example, can be ran successfully through the Windows -> Linux tunnel as expected. This problem is to my knowledge isolated to Nmap, but I struggle to understand why / if there is anything I can do about it. **UPDATE: The other working tools ALSO produce the same error in the SSH debug output, it just doesn't appear to impact their performance**

I did find a [Nmap GitHub issue from 2019](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/1596) regarding all ports returning open which was closed as a 'wontfix' because `This is most likely the behavior of your proxy, but it could be caused by Proxychains-ng itself. It is not a bug in Nmap, and Nmap has no control over this behavior.` I'm also struggling to find another port scanner that is compatible with socks proxies and isn't a fancy wrapper for Nmap underneath.

As I have been learning, SSH is highly configurable both server and client side, so I'm hoping someone might be able to identify a configuration change that could resolve this behavior. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.